# Codeigniter URL / HMVC ambiguity

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter, hmvc

If I have the following structure in codeigniter with the use of wireddesign's HMVC extension, what will happen?

**Module** : Yellowpages
**Controller** : Yellowpages
**Method** : Listing

**Module** : Yellowpages
**Controller** : Listing
**Method** : index

If I access the URL `www.site.com/yellowpages/listing` , what will happen? Will it route to `listing` method in `yellowpages` controller or will it route to the `listing` controller?

Answer (score 0):

I checked for this scenario and i got the answer that this will call

**Module :** yellowpages **Controller :** Listing **Method :** index

In CI, it check first for the controller and got the Listing controller so called Listing controller with its index function

Here, you need to change module name to lowercase otherwise will get error of page not found for url: www.site.com/yellowpages/listing or you can change url to www.site.com/Yellowpages/listing. but mostly we are using urls in lowercase.